# passing format string to scanf as an command line argument vs hardcoding it

Tags: c, scanf

I have following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char c;
    char *format_string = "%d\n";
    scanf(format_string, &i);
    printf("read: %d\n", i);

    printf("Let's check what is in the input buffer:\n");
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
    {
        printf("read from input buf: %d\n", c);
    }
}
```

If I run the code following way:

```
echo "5" | ./specific.out
```

The output is following:

```
read: 5
Let's check what is in the input buffer:
```

Here I have more general version of above code, where I pass format string from command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    int i;
    char c;

    char *format_string = argv[1];

    scanf(format_string, &i);
    printf("read: %d\n", i);

    printf("Let's check what is in the input buffer:\n");
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
    {
        printf("read from input buf: %d\n", c);
    }
}
```

If I run the code following way:

```
echo "5" | ./general.out '%d\n'
```

The output is following:

```
read: 5
Let's check what is in the input buffer:
read from input buf: 10
```

Why do I get different outputs?

Comment: Because the loop reads the newline that `echo` adds, which you print as decimal (\n=10 in ascii)

Comment: Sure, but why doesn't the first version do the same thing?

Comment: To make them both work the same way, use `"%d%*c"` as the format string.

Comment: @user3386109 can you please explain what following format string does? Thanks

Comment: `%d` reads the integer. `%*c` reads one more character and discards it.

Comment: The other option is to use `"%d "` in the code, and `'%d '` on the command line, because a newline in a `scanf` format string does exactly the same thing as a space character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you specify `'%d\n'` on the command line, you're not sending a `%` followed by `d` followed by a newline.  You sending `%` followed by `d` followed by `\` followed by `n`.

Because of this, the newline generated by the `echo` command doesn't match anything in the format string (specifically a newline doesn't match `\`), so it gets left in the input buffer.

To get the same result, your command line would have to look like this:

```
echo "5" | ./x1 '%d
'
```

On a side note, it's a bad idea for a format string to be under the control of a user, as that can lead to a [format string vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack).  Format strings are best left as string literals.

As an added bonus, if you use a string literal as a format string then your compile will also be able to generate warnings if the format string doesn't match the parameters passed to it.

Comment: thank you for an answer. I've figured out that I can use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in bash to achieve same. So my command look like this `echo "5" | ./general.out $'%d\n'`

Comment: can you please point me to some resources about your last statement that compiler can generate warnings if the format string  doesn't match the parameters passed to it. Thx